# How to make pages not use the masterpage in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, master-pages

I have an MVC3 site where I have some pages that I don't want to use the master page layout.  The default master page is specified in the _ViewStart file so gets applied to everything.

How do I configure things so that some pages are displayed without the master page ?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just place `@{ Layout = null; }` at the beginning of your view file.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really clear if you mean to ask "how do I render a partial view?" or "how do i choose a different master page?"

If you want to render partial just use

```
@Html.Partial()
```

If you want to change the layout add someting like ..

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MySwankyLayout.cshtml";
}
```

If you want no layout ..

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Layout property of that specific page, e.g. in Razor:

```
@{
 Layout = ...
}
```